スクリプトから PostgreSQL のユーザーパスワードを変更する方法は？
環境
OS：Debian11
やりたいこと
OSインストール後に、環境セットアップとしてスクリプトファイルを管理者権限で実行して、postgresqlのデフォルトユーザpostgresに対して、指定したパスワードを変更したい。
以下の記述ではダメでした。
sudo -u postgres PGPASSWORD='password'

passwdコマンドであると、ユーザーの入力が必要となるため、ユーザー入力を必要としない方法はないでしょうか？
debian10では上記コマンドで動作していました。

自己解決したので、投稿します。
スクリプトの記述
echo "postgres:<password>" | chpasswd
sed -i -e '/^local[ ]*all[ ]*postgres[ ]*peer/ s/peer/md5/' /etc/postgresql/*/main/pg_hba.conf
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER postgres with encrypted password '<password>';"
systemctl restart postgresql.service

このコマンドにより、以下のようにpsqlにログインできるようになります。
# psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres:<input password>
psql (13.17 (Debian 13.17-0+deb11u1))
Type "help" for help

postgres=# 


実際には試していませんが、英語版での How can I change a PostgreSQL user password? の回答の一つに、以下の方法が紹介されていました。

sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD '<new-password>';"



うまくいきませんでした。
